# G Suite SSO error app_not_configured_for_user

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, google-apps, google-workspace

I am integrating Google G Suite SAML/SSO into our company web application. I have set up all necessary fields in our G Suite admin account, as well as in our service provider code.

Here are the cases where the login works great when attempting to access our web app:

1. Not logged into any Google accounts: Redirects me to Google "Choose an account" page. I log into my company account, and I am redirected to my application.
2. Logged into both my company Google account and my personal Google account (in the same browser): Redirects me to Google "Choose an account" page. I choose my company account, and I am redirected to my application.

This is the case where the login behaves less than ideal:

1. I am logged into only my personal Google account. I attempt to access my company application and I am redirected to a Google 403 error page that tells me "Error: app_not_configured_for_user / Service is not configured for this user.". There are no links to choose a different account, and I am stuck on that page until I open another tab, log into my company Google account, then, open another tab and attempt to access my application again (which I am then taken to the choose account page).

This is a common scenario and could be quite irritating if this SSO implementation is delivered like this.
Ideally, in this scenario, I would like the user to be shown the "Choose an account" page, instead of this 403 error page. Even a nicer message would be better.

I have spent quite a while looking for any setting that I am missing in my G Suite admin account, as well as any additional parameters I can send in the authentication request, because I don't want my users to ever see this error page and wonder what is going on.

Has anyone ran into this situation before? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml/issues/116

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did check that out, and unfortunately no solution was found. I did, however, get a response from g suite support, and they told me that this is how things currently work, and that there is something in the pipeline to change this behavior.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. It's now a year later, did you ever find out a solution?

Comment: Also experiencing this problem.

Comment: @velotron, no we did not find a solution to this, and decided a short time after to go in a different direction with our login system.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, i faced the same issue. I have a node application that uses gsuite as an identity provided (sso connection). the app was well configured but every time i tried to connect to my app i had this famous error app_not_configured_for_user.

So, the problem in my case was the http and i solved it by trasforming my node application from using http to use https protocol and i changed my callback address from http://my-domain:3000/login/callback to https://my-domain:3000/login/callback.

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This response is more than a year later but if someone still having the same issue here is some information:

The App not configured by the user is a 403 error, you can check for more details here https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301076?hl=en. Usually this is an error when the application is not properly setup for that specific user, could be that the email address is different from the one on the application and the account or that there is a problem with the SP initiated flow.

I would suggest to contact G Suite support and request to speak with the SSO team, they should be able to assist you. Sometimes just by uploading the certitificate again resolves the issue but it worth to investigate first, since sometines it is necesary to record a HAR file for further investigation. I hope this helps Greetings.